# How to stop redis-server autostart

Tags: ubuntu, redis, autostart

I am using Ubuntu to develop my website.  Recently, I started to use redis.

When I started my computer, redis-server will start by its own.

What method can I stop my redis-server starting by itself?

Comment: // , Please post your version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It seems that the `redis-server` package uses `rc.d` scripts, and the preferred way to deal with them in Ubuntu is using `update-rc.d`:

```
sudo update-rc.d redis-server disable
```

Should do the trick. You can also disable it in a certain runlevel only:

```
sudo update-rc.d redis-server disable 2
```

Comment: did **not work** for me, getting `update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/redis-server: file does not exist` warning. Using **Ubuntu 14.04 & Redis 3.0.7** which is the latest version available.

Comment: @talha06 did you install the redis-server deb package using apt, or did you build it from sources or another installation method?

Comment: I built it from the sources since it is the way Redis guides: http://redis.io/download

Comment: That explains it, this advice is for the Ubuntu package of redis. I don't know how vanilla redis handles init scripts, but [this part of the README](https://github.com/antirez/redis#installing-redis) says it will be called "redis_<portnumber>", so `sudo update-rc.d redis_6379 disable` should work if it's on the default port.

Comment: @LinusGustavLarssonThiel that indeed works! Thanks, maybe it would make sense to edit the original answer?

Comment: This answer is outdated, see the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857198/how-to-stop-redis-server-autostart/51140929#51140929

Answer (score 35):

For those looking for a more up-to-date solution. If your system is using systemd (Ubuntu 15.04 and up) the way to not launch it at start-up is:

```
sudo systemctl disable redis-server
```

systemctl admits "basically" these actions (check the following links for the complete list)

- `disable`. Don't launch at boot.
- `enable`. Launch at boot.
- `start`. Launch it now.
- `stop`. Stop it now.
- `status`. To check if is running

As written in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/699015/499290):

> For more details, see [enabling-and-disabling-services](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2006/04/enabling-and-disabling-services-during_01.html) and for the very long answer see this [post](https://askubuntu.com/q/19320/425630)
>
> For more details, see this post on [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units) and the [man page for systemctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html).